# Custom permalinks in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, slug

I have a question about permalinks that has me crazy because I have not found a solution for a long time  So I turn to the wisdom of the hive mind to see if it sheds some light on me.

I have my WordPress permalinks activated in /%postname%/

And then I have pages with the following hierarchy:

```
- Page 1
-- Page 2
--- Page 3
```

Those pages load dynamic content thanks to an id that passes through the url, but I would like the url to be friendly from the dynamic title field.

I explain:

Page 1 is loaded with the correct url that looks like this:

`https://www.example.com/page-1/`

Once there, to Page 2 I pass an id whose url looks like this:

`https://www.example.com/page-1/page-2/?id=6`

But, what I really want is for the url to be like this:

`https://www.example.com/page-1/get-name-dynamically/`

And the same with Page 3, which now looks like this:

`https://www.example.com/page-1/page-2/page-3/?id=8`

But I would like it to look like this:

`https://www.example.com/page-1/get-name-dynamically-cooking/other-dynamic-name/`

I don't know how to pass the dynamic slugs

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you'd do better keeping the slugs in the post table up to date. How have you implemented dynamic slugs?

Comment: I haven't implemented it, that's what I want to do hahahaha. To be able to get the slug from the url and the url changes :S

Answer (score -1):

hi here is the solution if you are asking about custom url.
go to pages
and edit page ( note that download classic editor first)
you can easily create a custom permalink with a classic editor.
once you download a classic editor in your WordPress then it is so easy to create custom url for your pages.
you can just try it.
if your problem did not solve then ask here again

Comment: Thanks for your response!! But I don't understand... Where I can put a dinamical slug?

Comment: This "answer" needs much more detail... saying "you can easily create a custom permalink with a classic editor" does not answer the question. How does this relate to the specific example in the question?